# Flink Table,Create table Array type error "ValidationException"

Tags: java, apache-flink, clickhouse, flink-sql, flink-table-api

I created a flink table that contains data type fields, and the error type does not match。
I want to know how to create a temporary table containing an array type in a flink table.

```
public class FlinkConnectorClickhouse {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // create environments of both APIs
        StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        StreamTableEnvironment tableEnv = StreamTableEnvironment.create(env);

        // create a DataStream
        DataStream<Order> dataStream = env.fromCollection(Arrays.asList(
                new Order(2L, "pen", 1, Arrays.asList("name01", "name02", "name03"), Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)));
        Table inputTable = tableEnv.fromDataStream(dataStreamMap, $("user").as("user_a"), $("product"), $("amount"), $("name_list"), $("id_list"));

        // register the Table object as a view and query it
        tableEnv.createTemporaryView("InputTable", inputTable);

        tableEnv.executeSql("CREATE TABLE sink_table (\n" +
                "    `user_a` BIGINT,\n" +
                "    `product` VARCHAR,\n" +
                "    `amount` BIGINT,\n" +
                "    `name_list` ARRAY<STRING>,\n" +
                "    `id_list` ARRAY<INT>,\n" +
                "    PRIMARY KEY (user_a) NOT ENFORCED /* 如果指定 pk，进入 upsert 模式 */\n" +
                ") WITH (\n" +
                ")");

        TableResult resultTable = tableEnv.executeSql("INSERT INTO sink_table SELECT user_a, product, amount,name_list,id_list FROM InputTable");
        env.execute();
    }
    public static class Order {
        private Long user;
        private String product;
        private Integer amount;
        private List<String> name_list;
        private List<Integer> id_list;
}
```

Comment: What does the error message say?

Answer (score 0):

```
            ") WITH (\n" +
            ")");
```

is probably where it's going wrong. Where is your sink connector? Is it Kafka? It is Hive? Is it a regular database with JDBC?

You'll find a list under the "Table API connectors" here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/connectors/table/overview/. Be sure that you follow the right JAR packaging/deployment/management policy.

If you're a beginner, you might be interested in this one which is bundled with Flink:

```
) WITH (
  'connector' = 'filesystem',           -- required: specify the connector
  'path' = 'file:///path/to/whatever',  -- required: path to a directory
  'format' = 'csv'                     -- required: file system connector requires to specify a format,
)
```

or this one:

```
WITH (
  'connector' = 'print'
);
```

or this one:

```
WITH (
  'connector' = 'blackhole'
);
```